# Custom adapter list view is not getting refreshed

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

Here is my adapter class.

```
 public class CustomListViewAdapterRetailList extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {


Context context;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;


public CustomListViewAdapterRetailList(Context context,
        int textViewResourceId, List<RowItem> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}


/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView retailerImage;
    TextView retailerName;
    TextView retailerSlogan;
    TextView msgDesc;
    ImageView typeImage;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.retailer_list_list_item,
                null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.retailerImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.retailer_list_item_iv_icon);
        holder.retailerName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.retailer_list_item_tv_title);
        holder.retailerSlogan = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.retailer_list_item_tv_slogan);
        holder.msgDesc = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.retailer_list_item_tv_msg);
        holder.typeImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.retailer_list_item_iv_type);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    //downloading image
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(Perma.uImageRetailer[position],
            holder.retailerImage);

    holder.retailerName.setText(rowItem.getuNameRetailer());
    holder.retailerSlogan.setText(rowItem.getuSloganRetailer());
    holder.msgDesc.setText(rowItem.getuDescRetailer());
    holder.typeImage.setImageResource(rowItem.getUtypeMsg());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Here is my main activity.

```
ListView retailListView;
List<RowItem> retailRowItems;
CustomListViewAdapterRetailList adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.retailer_list);

    lSearch = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlist_ll_top);
    searchBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rlist_et_search);
    startSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rlist_bt_search_initiate);

    retailRowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    Log.i("in retailer list",""+Perma.retailerArrayLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < Perma.retailerArrayLength; i++) {
        Log.i("in retailer list","infor");
        RowItem item = new RowItem(Perma.uNameRetailer[i],
                Perma.uSloganRetailer[i], Perma.uImageRetailer[i],
                Perma.uDescRetailer[i], Perma.typeRetailer[i]);
        Log.i("retailer list",""+Perma.uNameRetailer[i]+""+Perma.uImageRetailer[i]);
        retailRowItems.add(item);
    }

    retailListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rlist_lv);


    // i tried to clear data but it clears whole list and does not populate with new data.
    /*   if(adapter!=null){
        adapter.clear();}
            */

    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapterRetailList(this,
            R.layout.retailer_list_list_item, retailRowItems);

    retailListView.setAdapter(adapter);     

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    retailListView.invalidateViews();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Now the thing is 
user clicks a button , a dialog appears , user select checkboxes and hit Ok.
then new data is loaded.

I have tried clear(), invalidate() and notifyDataSetChanged()
but they are not working.

Please help me out here, and please give answers in context of my code because I'm still a newbie.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: How do you load new data? You need to add it to your adapter first before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: How ? i didnt knew that..

Comment: You can use `adapter.add(item)` then `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: can you show me where and how ...

Comment: sorry i don't see your code. You need to do it in your new data loading code which you mentioned

Comment: @user527759  this is whole code.and i'm using asynch task to load new data. so where do i use this code ???

Comment: so in that AsyncTask you need to add new items to your adapter.

Comment: @user527759 thank you mate !! i got the answer and i have updated it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


 /// here i used it in resume because my data was changing because of user interaction with dialog. so its should be in in resume.

    if(!retailRowItems.isEmpty()){
    ///now if row is populated clear its data
        retailRowItems.clear();

            ///populate again  
    for (int i = 0; i < Perma.retailerArrayLength; i++) {

        RowItem item = new RowItem(Perma.uNameRetailer[i],
                Perma.uSloganRetailer[i], Perma.uImageRetailer[i],
                Perma.uDescRetailer[i], Perma.typeRetailer[i]);

        retailRowItems.add(item);       

    }

    }
            ///notify adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override your adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() method:

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
   super.notifyDataSetChanged();
   //refresh your List<RowItem> objects here
}
```